# Paperback ID: power armor/war robot theme; minimalist cover art

Tags: story-identification, robots, armor

I saw a book in a used bookstore around 2005 in Ontario, Canada whose cover art really caught my eye. Unfortunately, I didn't end up picking it up, and it's been bugging me ever since.

While I saw it around 2005 or so, it seemed to be far older; it seemed more like a '60s or '70s pulp paperback, and was relatively thin, I'd say about 200-300 pages.

The cover art itself was somewhat minimalist; it was plain white, with a monochromatic, almost wood-cut-style image on it in brown or black (similar to [this](https://www.fantascienza.com/catalogo/imgbank/cover/01204.jpg)). It almost seems to me like it may have originally been interior art from a magazine like *Astounding*, *Galaxy*, etc, adapted into cover art. I also seem to recall the paper for the cover itself was very fibrous and low-gloss, almost like canvas or Bristol board.

The image itself was of a steampunk-looking humanoid robot or soldier in power armour, with the suggestion of a warzone in the background. The figure was in mid-stride past, while looking directly toward the perspective of the cover. The figure itself was fairly thin - it's possible at least the limbs were mechanical "pipes" and wires - and the head consisted of a slightly tall and pointed helmet (reminiscent of a British pith helmet) with round-lensed goggles. A good reference of both pose and general look can be seen [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-U7SDDDcBql4/VSkrZmVExcI/AAAAAAAADEQ/_vUQSGUiKsU/s1600/60030116001_CodexSkitarii01.jpg).

I could be wrong, but I seem to recall the title had the word "Armor" (or "Armour") in it, though searching both on IMDB returned nothing similar - it's not *[Armored](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?372465)*, *[Body Armor 2000](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?5161)*, or [*Armor*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2408). It's possible it was an anthology of stories involving power armor or war robots, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: When it's about power armors, there are obligatory references to both Heinlein's Starship Troopers and Haldeman's Forever War. Speaking of the latter, there's a (Dutch?) cover on the Isfdb that might fit your description: http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/9/9a/DWGRLGGNPJ1978.jpg

Comment: As a follow up to the previous comment, this cover of Starship Troopers also might fit: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?75970

Comment: @ZabZonk Thanks for sharing. I did notice the second cover, and it is similar, but it's not a match. The cover I saw was monocromatic (I'll update my question to be a bit more clear about this). On that note, it also reminds me of this cover for the Forever War, which was what I bought instead of the one I'm asking about. http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/f/f0/THFRVRWR1976.jpg

Comment: I had a thought; your description reminds me of some small-press books I'd occasionally see being self-promoted at cons (back when I used to go), so I did some checking.  I looked up a couple of Canadian small-press publishers that have a few SF/fantasy titles, and none of the books, their authors or the publishers show up in ISFDb.  I didn't go into great detail, or see if US publisher coverage is better, it just suggests that books can fall between the cracks and might not be findable in ISFDb.

Comment: @DavidW Interesting suggestion. I didn't get the impression that the book was small-press or "indie" since the paper quality and whatnot seemed on par with a lot of other pulpy books from the 60's/70's, but I couldn't say for sure. Can you suggest an example of one of these publishers, or a means of looking into this further?

Comment: I started from [this list of publishers of SF&F books](https://publishersarchive.com/science-fiction-book-publishers.html) (which I found in a Google search), and looked for ones in Canada ("   CA").  Of the ones in Canada, 2 of the first 3 (5310 Publishing, Blue Moon Publishers, and Bundoran Press) don't appear in ISFDb (Blue Moon does).  Note that Bundoran appears to be defunct, which makes figuring out what they _did_ publish difficult.  Note also that this appears to be a _current_ list of publishers; finding defunct small press publishers from 20 years ago is something I haven't solved.

Comment: I assume the Language was in English? Do you remember if it was from a USA Publisher, or a Canadian publisher?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a quick look into it but it may be a bit too much of a rabbit hole for me.

Comment: @NJohnny I'm almost certain it was in English, unless it was put in the wrong place. I'm pretty sure the blurb on the back was English though. I'm also thinking it was an American publisher, but I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found it! It's **[War Games by Brian Stableford](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?185249)**. The edition in particular is the book's first printing, 1981, by Pan Books. The artist is Ian Miller.

[image: Cover art for War Games by Brian Stableford]

It's not *exactly* how I described it - it'd been a long time since I'd seen it - but the pose, outfit, and art style fit barring a few minor details.

Comment: Ian Miller's work is pretty great.

Answer (score 4):

The description of the cover art is close to that on [this edition](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/adam-link-robot-by-eando-binder-1st-paperback-library-edition-september-1965--440789882261370771/) of *Adam Link: Robot*, by Eando Binder.  This novel was a fixup of a dozen stories published between 1939 and 1942, but was reissued several times as late as the 1970s, and at least one version of the cover art catches most of the remembered details.

This is probably the earliest story series to treat the robot as the protagonist, one of the earliest to make the robot a sympathetic, even heroic figure rather than a menace.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's not it, though. The one I've been looking for is more monochromatic, like a woodcut or pencil sketch.